# From run block can i able to call angular scope function inside another controller instead of $rootscope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I need to call angular Scope function inside some controller from runblock. can i able to call the function or else need to use rootScope or $scope.apply.

First method:

```
myAPP.run(function ($rootScope, $state,$scope) {

  $scope.menupage();

});

 var SampleController = function ($scope,$localStorage) {

$scope.menupage =function()
{
// some logic
};
});

    SampleController.$inject = ['$scope','$localStorage'];
```

Else need to use  like this

```
myAPP.run(function ($rootScope, $state,$scope) {

 $scope.$apply(function() {
  $scope.menupage();

});

});



var SampleController = function ($scope,$localStorage) {


$scope.menupage =function()
{


// some logic
};


});
SampleController.$inject = ['$scope','$localStorage'];
```

Comment: The `run` block only has $rootScope. It does not have a $scope of its own.

Comment: $rootScope.$apply is available as well as all the $rootScope.Scope methods: $watch, $eval, $on, $broadcast, etc. For more information, see [AngularJS $rootScope.Scope API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Answer (score 0):

```
myAPP.run(function ($rootScope, $state,$scope) {
```

You can't have `$scope` object as a third parameter here, because both `$scope` and `$controller` objects are created during `compiling and linking phase`, which follows `run` phase during which `run` blocks are executed. So you can't have them in your run blocks. Only the `$rootScope` is available in `run` blocks since it's a service and only services are available in `run` blocks.

Comment: Because i have call the function when button click  and some scenario i have to use in run block ,so i plan to reusable code. In this situation can i use rootscope or else any other way as reusable .

Comment: That is not true. All the services are available, $http, $timeout, $q, etc. $scope is not available because it is not a service.

Comment: @georgeawg, of course all services are available, I didn't phrase it correctly. I edited

Comment: @Maximus got it what you are saying, I will use service to call it for both blocks. thanks for your prompt replies!!

Comment: @MohamedSahir, sure, you can upvote or accept the answer if it suits you